# mysql - always get MAX id from table

Tags: php, mysql

If I have a bunch of inserts going on into a table and I execute a select statement to get the last id, will the select wait until all the inserts are done? Is There some difference if I use MAX or last_insert_id?

Right now I'm using:

```
SELECT MAX(ID) as myid FROM MY_TABLE WHERE my_column = "my_condition";
```

Comment: It sounds like you want an `auto_increment` column, so you are not setting the `id` explicitly when you insert values.

Comment: you have to understand about mutli tasking (threading), each request will be handled by different process/handlers,

Comment: but while I doing the inserts, I can guarantee that the select will always return the last inserted ID?

Answer (score 2):

> will the select wait until all the inserts are done?

Nope. Why would it? If the insert queries were issued before the SELECT query and it's a MyISAM table, then yes, you'll get the id of the last insert. That such queries are serialized are the reason that most people use InnoDB for OLTP.

> Is There some difference if I use MAX or last_insert_id?

Yes. last_insert_id wil return the last id generated by *your* session, while MAX(id) will return the *greatest* integer assigned by any session before your query was run - auto_increment integers do not alwayts increase monotonically.

Unless you know exactly what you are doing, and are deliberately doing something very odd, last_insert_id will give you the answer you are looking for and will be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you use MAX, you will always get the greatest number in the database. That is like use a AUTO_INCREMENT.

When you use "last_insert_id" you get the last insert id, so if you insert something in the id 4, but your max id is 10, you have to check if is something between 4 and 10.

I recommend you use "MAX" or configure it correctly the AUTO_INCREMENT in the database